# joins numbers together into a file

Tags: python, numbers, extract

i have a list of numbers, i will like to join or write them them together into a text file and put the sum of the numbers in the file.

```
[0.297, 0.344, 0.342, 0.285, 0.333, 0.337, 0.309, 0.334, 0.337, 0.289, 0.342, 0.337, 0.292, 0.337, 0.347, 0.31, 0.335, 0.34, 0.279, 0.331, 0.336, 0.298, 0.338, 0.347, 5.357, 0.342, 0.314, 0.289, 0.358, 0.341, 0.321, 0.336, 0.347, 0.3, 0.336, 0.333, 0.279, 0.334, 0.339, 0.303, 0.335, 0.337, 0.301, 0.329, 0.337, 0.289, 0.335, 0.341, 0.305, 0.332, 0.347, 0.307, 0.332, 0.344, 0.291, 0.334, 0.333, 0.347, 0.345, 0.342, 0.297, 0.338, 0.35, 0.329, 0.336, 0.345, 0.309, 0.344, 0.344, 0.288, 0.332, 0.341, 0.311, 0.343, 0.344, 0.319, 0.332, 0.335, 0.297, 0.337, 0.344, 0.297, 0.334, 0.341, 0.306, 0.332, 0.335, 0.299, 0.332, 0.344, 0.286, 0.332, 0.344, 5.362, 0.348, 0.318, 0.296, 0.345, 0.338, 0.305, 0.343, 0.343, 0.297, 0.332, 0.331, 0.296, 0.334, 0.336, 0.305, 0.341, 0.346, 0.286, 0.337, 0.334, 0.306, 0.342, 0.342, 0.305, 0.332, 0.335, 0.285, 0.331, 0.335, 0.285, 0.334, 0.343, 0.308, 0.333, 0.341, 0.286, 0.338, 0.336, 0.306, 0.342, 0.335, 0.305, 0.342, 0.332, 0.296, 0.332, 0.342, 0.296, 0.342, 0.336, 0.307, 0.343, 0.347, 0.313, 0.328, 0.344, 0.313, 0.338, 0.334, 0.299, 0.337, 0.35, 0.292, 0.348, 0.341, 0.289, 0.335, 0.339, 5.366, 0.358, 0.343, 0.3, 0.338, 0.341, 0.306, 0.343, 0.345, 0.296, 0.332, 0.352, 0.296, 0.333, 0.346, 0.306, 0.342]
```

i want them to be on a single row and put the sum on top of the row like

```
sum = 2223.2
numbers are 
0.322
0.223
0.312
```

I tried joining with float,  but i am having errors

```
blut = '\n'.join(float(diffs))
open('ext.txt', 'w').write(blut)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [0.297, 0.344, 0.342, 0.285, 0.333, 0.337, 0.309, 0.334, 0.337, 0.289, 0.342, 0.337, 0.292, 0.337, 0.347, 0.31, 0.335, 0.34, 0.279, 0.331, 0.336, 0.298, 0.338, 0.347, 5.357, 0.342, 0.314, 0.289, 0.358, 0.341, 0.321, 0.336, 0.347, 0.3, 0.336, 0.333, 0.279, 0.334, 0.339, 0.303, 0.335, 0.337, 0.301, 0.329, 0.337, 0.289, 0.335, 0.341, 0.305, 0.332, 0.347, 0.307, 0.332, 0.344, 0.291, 0.334, 0.333, 0.347, 0.345, 0.342, 0.297, 0.338, 0.35, 0.329, 0.336, 0.345, 0.309, 0.344, 0.344, 0.288, 0.332, 0.341, 0.311, 0.343, 0.344, 0.319, 0.332, 0.335, 0.297, 0.337, 0.344, 0.297, 0.334, 0.341, 0.306, 0.332, 0.335, 0.299, 0.332, 0.344, 0.286, 0.332, 0.344, 5.362, 0.348, 0.318, 0.296, 0.345, 0.338, 0.305, 0.343, 0.343, 0.297, 0.332, 0.331, 0.296, 0.334, 0.336, 0.305, 0.341, 0.346, 0.286, 0.337, 0.334, 0.306, 0.342, 0.342, 0.305, 0.332, 0.335, 0.285, 0.331, 0.335, 0.285, 0.334, 0.343, 0.308, 0.333, 0.341, 0.286, 0.338, 0.336, 0.306, 0.342, 0.335, 0.305, 0.342, 0.332, 0.296, 0.332, 0.342, 0.296, 0.342, 0.336, 0.307, 0.343, 0.347, 0.313, 0.328, 0.344, 0.313, 0.338, 0.334, 0.299, 0.337, 0.35, 0.292, 0.348, 0.341, 0.289, 0.335, 0.339, 5.366, 0.358, 0.343, 0.3, 0.338, 0.341, 0.306, 0.343, 0.345, 0.296, 0.332, 0.352, 0.296, 0.333, 0.346, 0.306, 0.342]

with open("file.txt", "w+") as f:
    s = sum(l)
    f.write("sum = {}\n".format(s))
    f.write("\n".join(map(str, l)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all the numbers in `diff` to strings first and then join them with a `\n`:

```
output = list(map(str, diffs))
blut = '\n'.join(output)
```

the extra `list()` is for Python 3.X and is redundant in Python 2.7. This assumes that your initial list is called `diffs`.

There are more ways to create the target output file. You can for instance use `join` to write the sum, text, and numbers all at once,

```
with open('ext.txt', 'w') as fout:
    fout.write(''.join(['sum = ', str(sum(diffs)), '\nnumbers are\n', blut]))
```

here the sum is also directly computed in the input list to `join` and converted to a string. `blut` is already a list of strings. `join` uses an empty string as a delimiter since all necessary spaces and newlines are included in the input list.

Another way would be to split the writing and add the sum first, then text, then numbers. In that case you would need to change `w` to append i.e. `a` after the first write.

Comment: where will the output file be saved?

Comment: I thought you had that covered :) I'll add it.. - just to check, you want to have the sum there, that line of text, and all the numbers?

Comment: You can append this bit into the file where you wrote the sum and the text, for instance.

Comment: is it possible to write, like the sum in the file. like at the bottom or top to put sum= 2222 for example

Comment: Yes, definitely. `sum` is a builtin function so better not use that name literally since you'll be overwriting it. Do you want me to add that part?

Comment: yeah, if possible. Thanks